# Can the question I asked, put on hold, be marked as answered?

Tags: support

I asked the question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86494/what-version-of-linux-fedora-to-install-and-how-to-do-it. I was going to edit it, but I think the answers/comments given are already sufficient for me to go ahead. I would mark it as answered, but there is no place to do that. Can someone do that for me? No need for a personal answer, seeing it closed will be a sufficient result for me. Thank you for a very well organised and incredibly useful facility, to me it is the best of all the forums etc. available.

Answer (score 3):

There is no answer to the question you refer to, so there is no answer to accept. Also, it is put on hold for a reason, namely, that it doesn't fit to this site for being an opinion-based question. I don't see an edit fixing this issue. You can, however, upvote the comment that help you out, these are the onse that are read most and you can reply with a comment that this was the solution you used.

Comment: Thank you, I will deal with that.